# How to add a button to call interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a app. but

How to add a button to call interface? like this

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqyfP.jpg

Comment: You can't touch the call interface api.

Comment: hmm,thanks. how about http://i.stack.imgur.com/g9wMz.jpg ?

Comment: Nope. You can't touch the call interface api.

Comment: okay~can i create a app which function is when i answered the phone, i can automatically jump to another page?

Comment: I don't think so. :-)

Comment: you may hack the system on a jailbroken device, but your app will never pass the review procedure for AppStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: You can't. The Call interface is provided by iOS and we don't have access to it's UI components.